# Third party, who issues invoices in its name, instead of freelancers

Tags: payment, online

I have a translation agency, and we are working with freelancers from all around the world (but mostly from Hungary). Unfortunately, these freelancers are not able to issue invoices - most of the times. We are looking for a third party, who we can pay, we get an invoice, and it sends the money to the freelancer. I don’t know if it’s a thing.

We like to hire freelancers from Upwork, because we can get invoices from Upwork. So we are looking for something similar, but only for payments. We don't want it to be a freelancer website like upwork, fiverr, or peopleperhour. And of course, with the lower possible fees.

Comment: Haven't checked Upwork, but it it works like Elance, the invoices are actually in the name of the freelancer, i.e. the freelancer must be able to issue invoices (i.e. be properly registered with the relevant tax authorities).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance. It is also asking for a product recommendation, which is also off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

A freelancer must be able to issue invoices. If he/she can't, he/she is not a freelancer.

This requires them to register with the appropriate tax authorities (or set up a company), which is a process that varies from country to country. For people doing small amounts of work over the year, there are usually simplified procedures.

In some countries, such as France, you may find companies that will "hire" the freelancer as an employee, invoice you, and pay the freelancer wages like an employee (in France, this is called "[portage salarial](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portage_salarial)" or "portage"). This has long been considered as a grey area (check the very long section on legislation on the topic in the Wikipedia article), but is apparently now slightly more formalised.

Wikipedia also tells us that this is called an "[Umbrella company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_company)" in the english-speaking world, and is supposedly prevalent in the UK.

However, as far as I understand it, this would in all cases be country-specific, as they would need to register as an employer in the relevant country, and "hire" the freelancer as an employee (on a short contract basis), declare the wages paid, and pay all applicable national insurance/social security/taxes.

Note that in some countries, you may not need much documentation to justify a charge (the receipt for the payment may be enough), so you might consider setting up a company in such a country, and then use that company to invoice your in-country company.

Also, as I noted in my comment above, you might want to double-check the invoices you receive from Upwork. Most freelancer platforms generate invoices **on behalf** of the freelancer, so the freelancer must be legally allowed to issue those invoices (and delegate the generation to the platform). Check the details of the invoicing party on the invoice. If it's the freelancer, it's exactly the same as the freelancer generating the invoice themselves.

Finally, note that if the difficulty is not so much the right for the freelancer to generate the invoices, but for them to actually generate the invoice (i.e. they don't have a template, don't know what to write where...), you can resort to "self-invoicing". This means you generate the invoices in their name (as if it was them who generated it), and you send them a copy for their records. This requires you to get consent from them to generate the invoice, and you should of course check that they are allowed to generate such invoices (usually means having a local registration number). Of course, you'll have to deal with the various cases of VAT (most certainly reverse-charge for intra-EU invoices).